# twilio RequestValidator not working in python wsgi

Tags: python-3.x, twilio, mod-wsgi

first time using twilio's RequestValidator. It seems pretty basic so I can't really figure out what this error is though. It looks like some internal error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/twilio/request_validator.py", line 91, in get_values
    return param_dict.getall(param_name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getall'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/twilio/request_validator.py", line 95, in get_values
    return param_dict.getlist(param_name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getlist'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/yasbackend/smsreply.wsgi", line 57, in application
    request_valid = validator.validate(url, form, sig)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/twilio/request_validator.py", line 131, in validate
    self.compute_signature(uri_without_port, params), signature
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/twilio/request_validator.py", line 76, in compute_signature
    values = self.get_values(params, param_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/twilio/request_validator.py", line 98, in get_values
    return [param_dict[param_name]]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

My code is pretty basic

```
twsec = "mysecretauth"
url = "https://my.url.com/api/call"
form = POSTDATA
sig = env['HTTP_X_TWILIO_SIGNATURE']
validator = RequestValidator(twsec)
request_valid = validator.validate(url, form, sig)
```

where all 4 paramters are basic strings. twsec is my auth token as a string. url is the exact same string i put in the console that is making the request. I just defined it in my script for testing purposes. Form is the post data. Looks like a simple url encoded list. and sig is the sig = env['HTTP_X_TWILIO_SIGNATURE'], which I checked and its is getting it fine.

I am sure it is something basic, I just can't decipher the error. 
-------EDIT------
So it looks like the second parameter needs to be a dictionary. Not sure how it can successfully reconstruct this like that. but not I don't get an error I just get that it fails.

```
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
import os
import json
import psycopg2
import random
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
import traceback
import uuid
import datetime
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
import requests
from twilio.request_validator import RequestValidator
import html
import urllib.parse



def application(env, start_response):
    length= int(env.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', '0'))
    body =''
    if(length == 0):        
        start_response('400 Bad Request', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
        return [b"Bad Request"]
    body= env['wsgi.input'].read(length)
    form = body.decode('utf-8')
    #form = urllib.parse.unquote(form)    #Tried with this too
    ts = form.split("&")
    postdic = {}
    for keyval in ts:
        tss = keyval.split("=")
        postdic[tss[0]] = tss[1]
    sig = env['HTTP_X_TWILIO_SIGNATURE']
    url = '<hard coded url>'
    twsec = "<Hard coded secred for testing>"
    validator = RequestValidator(twsec)
    
    request_valid = validator.validate(url, postdic, sig)
```

postdic looks something like

```
{'ToCountry': 'US', 'ToState': '', 'SmsMessageSid': 'SM*****************5a', 'NumMedia': '0', 'ToCity': '', 'FromZip': '*****', 'SmsSid': 'SM00*******************5a', 'FromState': 'CA', 'SmsStatus': 'received', 'FromCity': '*******', 'Body': 'Ffhj', 'FromCountry': 'US', 'To': '%2B*******', 'ToZip': '', 'NumSegments': '1', 'MessageSid': 'SM00********************5a', 'AccountSid': 'A*****************b', 'From': '%2B********', 'ApiVersion': '2010-04-01'}
```

signature looks something like

```
sig=Q9W5cfXdTY89tJHJu1FOQH/7Oo0=
```

Answer (score 0):

ok After comparing the results to the djanog example I figured out the issue. Python3 requests have a bug in the urllib.parse.unquote that doesn't convert + to spaces, and the signature from twilio is NOT based on the raw encoded string, rather then the post dictionary string conversion prior to it being converted to a rul string. So the following will work for WSGI

```
from urllib import parse
from twilio.request_validator import RequestValidator

def application(env, start_response):
    length= int(env.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', '0'))
    body= env['wsgi.input'].read(length)
    twsec = '<authtoken>'
    validator = RequestValidator(twsec)
    form = body.decode('utf-8')
    form  = form.replace("+", " ")
    form = urllib.parse.unquote(form)
    ts = form.split("&")
    postdic = {}
    for keyval in ts:
        tss = keyval.split("=")
        postdic[tss[0]] = tss[1]
    sig = env['HTTP_X_TWILIO_SIGNATURE']
    url = 'https://myurl'    #this is the same url as shown in your account
    request_valid = validator.validate(url, postdic, sig)
```

I was looking through the Validoator github and there were some notes about having the port number listed on the url in some instances, so other calls may not work without :443 appended on the end but I didn't try. Just wanted to put that out there in case anyone is looking at this in the future